# XSLT conditionally processing sibling attributes

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML element like this:

```
<element addr="::" value="1">
```

Now, I want to change the value of `value` to `"0"`, if `addr` is `"::"`.
A logical solution for me would be something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="element/@*">
    <xsl:if test="@addr = '::'">
        <xsl:message>Matched</xsl:message>
        <xsl:attribute name="value">0</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

But this does not seem to work.
How can I correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your attempt doesn't work is that your template matches `"element/@*"` i.e. each and every attribute of `element`. Within that context, the condition `<xsl:if test="@addr = '::'">` will never return true, because neither attribute has (or can have) a child attribute named `addr`.

To modify only the `value` attribute, make your template match it expressly, either as:

```
<xsl:template match="@value">
```

or - if you have other elements with an attribute named `value` and you want to be sure to exclude those - as:

```
<xsl:template match="element/@value">
```

Then you can replace it (or not) conditionally by:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="../@addr = '::'">
        <xsl:attribute name="value">0</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:copy/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Alternatively, you could do it this way:

```
<xsl:template match="element[@value and @addr = '::']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="value">0</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

i.e. match the element that has the attribute that needs changing and overwrite that attribute.

Note that we are assuming here that you also have an *identity transform* template in place.

Answer (score 4):

Use an identity template that copies everything:

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

and override it with a template rule that modifies what you want to modify:

```
<xsl:template match="@value[../@addr = '::']">
  <xsl:attribute name="value">0</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```